# Facebook login with custom port

Tags: facebook, authentication, port, default

We have test web application that runs on not default port (example.com:3567).
For Facebook login we use hybridauth application(http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/)
Problem is that when I want to login to facebook with not dafault port in return link with port 80 (example.com)

In facebook app in Page url input I wrote page url with port (http://example.com:3567).

So question is can I use not default port for facebook login or only standard ports?